# What is the difference between these two commands

Tags: linux, unix

I have the following variables set in a script.

```
SU="/bin/su -s /bin/sh
WSO2_SCRIPT="JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME /opt/autopilot/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh"
WSO2_USER=autoplt
```

This part of the script is of concern:

```
 if [ "$RETVAL" -eq "0" ]; then
  if [ "$(whoami)" != "${WSO2_USER}" ]; then
   $SU - $WSO2_USER -c "${WSO2_SCRIPT} start" >> ${WSO2_LOG} 2>&1 || RETVAL="4"
  else
    ${WSO2_SCRIPT} start >> ${WSO2_LOG} 2>&1 || RETVAL="4"
  fi
fi
```

If I am root, then the following command gets executed:

```
/bin/su -s /bin/sh - autoplt -c 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest /opt/autopilot/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh start'
```

and

```
RETVAL
```

will get evaluated to 0.

When I am user autoplt, the following command gets executed:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest /opt/autopilot/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh start
```

However

```
RETVAL
```

will get evaluated to 4?

Are they not the same commands? Shouldn't RETVAL be 0 in each case?

The command gets executed successfully when I run it in the shell as autoplt user.

Therefore is there something wrong with the way I have written it?

Answer (score 0):

the double pipe `||` used in lines :

```
$SU - $WSO2_USER -c "${WSO2_SCRIPT} start" >> ${WSO2_LOG} 2>&1 || RETVAL="4"
${WSO2_SCRIPT} start >> ${WSO2_LOG} 2>&1 || RETVAL="4"
```

means if the first command succeed, then the second will not be executed
It means when running as root, it succeed then no change to RETVAL
and as a user, if fails so change RETVAL to 4

Comment: but why did the second one not succeed? it works if I do it in the shell

Comment: only difference I can see is the use of `/usr/java/latest` in commandline and not in script

Comment: but it gets evaluated to JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest /opt/autopilot/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh start, when I run the script?

Comment: what does your log `${WSO2_LOG}` says when running script as autoplt ? maybe your log can't be write by this user, so command fails and return 4.

Comment: /etc/init.d/autopilot-wso2is: line 112: JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest: No such file or directory